# How to check for existence of row in a joined table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm afraid I am quite a novice to MySQL.  I've done a lot of reading to try and solve this but for some reason haven't been able to make it work.

Hopefully one of you can help with what at first sight, should be quite simple

I have a query which selects a list of comments.

```
$commentquery = "select projects_comments.*, users.user_url, users.display_name
from ".$wpdb->prefix."projects_comments projects_comments
left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users users on   
users.ID=projects_comments.userid           
where projectid = '$projectid'
order by projects_comments.commentid desc";
```

Users can 'like/love' these comments (think facebook)

I would like to be able to check if the logged in user has liked/loved each comment returned from this query.

A third table ('comment_loves' which is not shown in the above query) contains commentid, userid, posttime and the logged in userid is accessible via the variable $userid.  This third table needs to be checked for each returned row of the query.

To summarise, essentially I need to add the following functionality to this query:

for each returned row , the `".$wpdb->prefix."` comments_loves table must be checked for the existence of a row `WHERE userid = $userid AND commentid = commentid` of the row.  If it exists then it returns 'true' or '1' into another column named loves.

I hope this is clear enough, and my apologies if this is a simple question to many of you.  Despite my attempts I have not been able to make this work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test right now, but something like this should work; added another left join to check your condition;

```
SELECT projects_comments.*, 
       users.user_url,
       users.display_name, 
       comments_loves.userid IS NOT NULL AS loves
FROM projects_comments projects_comments
LEFT JOIN users users 
  ON users.ID=projects_comments.userid  
LEFT JOIN comments_loves
  ON projects_comments.commentid = comments_loves.commentid AND 
     comments_loves.userid = '$userid'
WHERE projectid = '$projectid'
ORDER BY projects_comments.commentid DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I tried Tony's query first and it worked, I have now also tried yours and this also works.  Would your method of using IS NOT NULL be faster than Tony's method?  If so I will go with your method.  Thanks

Comment: I have remarked your answer as the correct one since I had to modify Tony's to make it work, even though it was almost there.  The only modification required in your answer was the table name comments_loves should have been comment_loves.  Aside from that it worked straight away.

Comment: @gordyr I'd say the end result once you modified his query is pretty much the same query, I just use a MySQL shortcut to avoid the CASE while he types it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an outer join to your loves tables

Something like

```
select projects_comments.*, users.user_url, users.display_name,
case when comment_loves.commentid is null then 0 else 1 end as loves
from ".$wpdb->prefix."projects_comments projects_comments
left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users users on users.ID=projects_comments.userid
outer join ".$wpdb->prefix."comment_loves 
on comment_loves.commentid = projects_comments.commentid
and comment_loves.userid = projects_comments.userid
where projectid = '$projectid'
order by projects_comments.commentid desc
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I got your query to work, however I had to use a 'left join' rather than outer join also had to 'and' part of the new join to check against $userid rather than projects_comments.userid.  Using the outer join it returned NULL results.  Regardless, it solves my problem so huge thanks!

Comment: Apologies for remarking Joachim with the correct answer Tony.  His query worked right out of the box however yours required a few modifications.  I hope you understand.  Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: Correct is correct. Guy seems to know a bit more than me, never seen teh IS not null trick in a Select clause. So you question taught me something as well.

Answer (score 0):

check for a returned row count using mysql_num_rows such as

```
$DBresult = mysql_query($yourQuery, $dbLink);
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($DBresult);

if($rowCount > 0)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not sure I understand how this would help.  Surely this would only check the number of rows in my Initial query when I actually want to check the number of rows of a 'third table' that match $userid for each commentid/row returned.  Or am I misunderstanding something?